# Custom Cursor Loader to use with SQLite database

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-cursorloader

I'm trying to use a custom implementation of a `CursorLoader` to use it with a SQLite database. I referred this link (https://gist.github.com/casidiablo/1217628) for the implementation.

```
public abstract class SimpleCursorLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor> {
    private Cursor mCursor;

    public SimpleCursorLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public abstract Cursor loadInBackground();
    ... 
    ...
}
```

Now in my Fragment, I created another class (`ShirtsCursorLoader`) which extends `SimpleCursorLoader` and defined the `loadInBackground()` method.

```
public static final class ShirtsCursorLoader extends SimpleCursorLoader {
    Context context;

    public ShirtsCursorLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllShirts();
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Now in the same Fragment, I also implemented `LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` interface and when I try implementing the `onCreateLoader()` function (which returns a `Loader<Cursor>` type), I am getting a type incompatible error.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        ShirtsCursorLoader loader = new ShirtsCursorLoader(getActivity());
        return loader;   // this line gives a type incompatible error
    else
        return null;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? It complains about type incompatibility, because it requires a `Loader<Cursor>` object to be returned but I'm returning a `ShirtsCursorLoader` object.

What I don't get is since the `CustomCursorLoader` is of the same type as the `CursorLoader` and the `ShirtsCursorLoader` extends `CustomCursorLoader`, then why is the type incompatible?